# Selecting a Table Cell

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, select, telerik

I have a table that is automatically generated based off of two Grid values.
I would like to be able to select each individual cell (not multiple cells), and on cell select, a `RadWindow` should appear. The selected cell's outer box should become bold. Within the RadWindow is a `RadColor` picker, and the color picked will change the cell's background.
I looked at a bunch of examples of similar events online, but because of my lack of `jQuery` and JS knowledge i'm unsure how to go about this.

My table looks like this:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="7px" 
    CellPadding="40" CellSpacing="15" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
    GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign = "Center">
</asp:Table>
```

The code-behind for the table generation is:

```
public void Generate_Matrix()
{
    // Total number of rows.

    int rowCnt = CCT.Rows.Count;

    // Current row count.
    int rowCtr;
    // Current cell counter
    int cellCtr = 0;
    // Total number of cells per row (columns).
    int cellCnt = LCT.Rows.Count;
    for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
    {
        // Create new row and add it to the table.
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tCell.Text = rowCtr + "" + cellCtr;
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem though?  What isn't working?

Comment: I am unsure how to implement this.
Actually, all I need to know is how to create a select-a-cell function, and the rest I could figure out myself.

Answer (score 0):

See how to work with RadGrid cells here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/cellselection/defaultcs.aspx
See how to call a function on the main page from inside the RadWindow here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx so you can pass the new color. OR use the ContentTemplate of the RadWindow so you have the color picker in the same context: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-calling-functions.html.
Store a reference to the last clicked cell in a global JS var for example. This can be done with the standard controls as well, you would needto extract the clicked cell from the event's target.